# jQuery DataTables retrieve multiple data-attributes from checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm using jQuery DataTables to create a data grid with which the first column contains a checkbox.

Here is the columnDefs where the checkboxes are created:

```
 "columnDefs":
 [
   {
     "targets": 0,
     "render": function(data, type, full, meta)
     {
       return '<input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxBooking" 
            data-booking="'+full[1]+'" data-quote="'+full[2]+'" data-line="'+full[3]+'" />';
     }
   }
 ]
```

Further down in the same file, I'm trying to retrieve all three of the data-attributes within each checkbox that was selected.

```
 $('#massAssigment').on('click', function()  // <-- button click
 {
   alert($('#checkBoxBooking:checked').map(function () {  // <-- alert box for now
     return $(this).attr('data-booking');
   }).get().join(";"));
 });
```

This where I got stuck.  I wasn't sure how to attach the other 2 data-attributes. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to get all of the data-attributes:

```
 return $(this).attr('data-booking')+','+$(this).attr('data-quote')+','+$(this).attr('data-line');
```

It's not pretty, but it works.  On to the next one.